# Not able to get my fetch request data to be saved as a local variable

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm building some code that has an API class that will fetch the data from the API and a model class that I am intending to use to store this data so that I can then display it later on. This is using an API that allows me to enter a postcode and get the longitutde and latitude coordinates returned.

API Class:

```
import apiKey from "../API/geocodingAPIKey.js";
import fetch from "node-fetch";


class GeocodingAPI {
    constructor(postcode) {
        this.postcode = postcode
    }

    fetchGeolocation(query, callback, errorCallback) {
        fetch(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${query}&key=${apiKey}`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            console.log("Load", data);
            callback(data.results);
        })
        .catch(() => {
                console.error("Error");
                errorCallback();
              });
        }
}

   
export default GeocodingAPI;
```

My model class:

```
class GeocodingModel{
    constructor(geocodingAPI){
        this.geocodingAPI = geocodingAPI
        this.postcode = geocodingAPI.postcode
    }

    fetchGeolocation(query = this.postcode ) {
      this.geocodingAPI.fetchGeolocation(
            query,
            (data) => {
              console.log('1')
              this.formatGeolocation(data);
              this.getGeolocation();
            },
            () => {
              this.displayError();
            }
          );
    }

    formatGeolocation(data){
      console.log('2')
      console.log(data)
      const geometry = data[0].geometry
      console.log(geometry)
      console.log('3')
      const lat = geometry.location.lat
      const lat4 = lat.toFixed(4)
      console.log('4')
      const long = geometry.location.long
      const long4 = long.toFixed(4)
      console.log('5')
      this.geolocation = `lat=${lat4}&lon=${long4}`
    }

    getGeolocation(){
      return this.geolocation
    }

    displayError(){
      console.log('Failed request')
    }
}

export default GeocodingModel
```

Check out this image: [My console shows where the error is happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCciJ.png)

The image shows that in my callback method in the model class, the chain gets stopped before I get to the console.log('5') I wrote. I am unable to store the data as a local variable, it seems like  when I store the geometry variable, it is not actually saving the data as a variable. Instead of it seems to be making another request?

This is the console log error:

```
geocodingAPI.js:18 Error
(anonymous)             @   geocodingAPI.js:18
Promise.catch (async)       
fetchGeolocation        @   geocodingAPI.js:16
fetchGeolocation        @   geocodingModel.js:8
./src/App.js            @   App.js:8
options.factory         @   react refresh:6
__webpack_require__     @   bootstrap:24
fn                      @   hot module replacement:62
./src/index.js          @   App.js:33
options.factory         @   react refresh:6
__webpack_require__     @   bootstrap:24
(anonymous)             @   startup:7
(anonymous)             @   startup:7
```

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: i don't see any `console.log('5')`

Comment: @dandavis I have updated it to the right code.

Comment: Well. You haven't told us what the error actually is. The screenshot (see [ask]: Post text, not pictures of text) shows the "expand this" error but you haven't done that. The error is also happening when you access something inside `geometry` but we can't see that (again, you've logged it but you haven't expanded the data so we can see what it actually is).

Comment: @Quentin Hi, I have edited to show the error.

Comment: No, you've edited it to show the result of `console.error("Error");` (not a useful error message at all) after you have caught and hidden the error thrown by whatever the problem is.

Comment: Don't make `fetchGeolocation` accept callbacks. Just return the promise!

Comment: `this.getGeolocation();` doesn't really make sense, the statement does nothing. It should be `console.log(this.getGeolocation());` or `this.displayGeolocation();` or something like that.